# I am really struggling to transfer data backwards to a UIView Controller

Tags: xcode, swift, delegates, protocols

I have several view controllers within a split view. With the one, clientViewController I have two text fields - "latitude" & "longitude"

I move onto a view controller that runs a map view etc. I post the latitude and longitude of the current location. In this I have a protocol and I have used the following code which seems to work fine:

```
protocol MappingViewControllerDelegate {
    func transferData(latitudeTfr: String!, longitudeTfr: String!)
}


class MappingViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, `MKMapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {`

var delegate: MappingViewControllerDelegate?
var latitudeTfr: String!
var longitudeTfr: String!

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    latitudeTfr = latitudeLabel.text!
    longitudeTfr = longitudeLabel.text!
    self.delegate?.transferData(latitudeTfr!, longitudeTfr: longitudeTfr!)
    print("Longitude is: \(longitudeTfr)")
    print("Latitude is: \(latitudeTfr)")

}
```

Back in the clientViewController I have the following but it does not seem to be fetching / transferring the data:

```
class ClientViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, MappingViewControllerDelegate {

func transferData(latitudeTfr: String!, longitudeTfr: String!) {
    self.latitudeText.text = "\(latitudeTfr!)"
    self.longitudeText.text = "\(longitudeTfr!)"
    print("\(latitudeTfr!)")
}
```

Somehere in the clientViewController I am missing something and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Wayne

Comment: I think you forgot to set the delegate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your protocol delegate to the viewcontroller that you're conforming.

Example:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("clientView") as! ClientViewController
vc.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```